# Inter VLAN with layer 2 and 3 switch

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, vlan, layer3

Is there a way to interconnect VLANs using this diagram?

MLS0 has this configuration:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
```

And SW0:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 175
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 176
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport mode trunk`
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get traffic from one VLAN to another VLAN, you need to use a router. The layer-3 switch could be used as a router. The hosts connected to each VLAN would use the SVI on the layer-3 switch for it VLAN as the gateway.

```
ip routing
!
interface Vlan175
 ip address 10.175.0.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
interface Vland176
 ip address 10.176.0.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
```

The PCs on VLAN 175 would use `10.175.0.1` as their gateway, and the PCs on VLAN 176 would use `10.176.0.1` as their gateway.

---

With two layer-3 switches (routers) you could use a FHRP (First Hop Redundancy Protocol), e.g. HSRP, to create a virtual gateway that the PCs use as their gateway, and the real routers will decide which is the active gateway, but will automatically fail over in the event of a router failure.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. I'm already using SVI on the layer-3 switchs for gateway for gateway purpose, but I don't gave connection.

Comment: @LuisAdriánTobar Did you set the host's default gateway as the SVI address for their respective VLAN?  Check out [this link](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/routing-between-vlans/#l3switch) for additional information on using and configuring L3 switches.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure connectivity between Different Vlan . Routing has to be done between both Vlans , Layer3 device is required for Configuring routing between Vlans . In router inter-Vlan routing need to be done to ensure connectivity between two Vlans by Configuring inter-Vlan routing .

In layer3 switch Switch virtual interfaces(SVI) need to be configured and enable" ip routing "